# I've killed the guy (Cale) who has the key open the door to the locked house in Mejula, is there a way to get it?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I accidentally killed him and now i have no way of getting the house key of the building Mejula. Anyone know of another way to get it?

Comment: I don't know if there's another way to get it, but if your concerned about what you are missing (spoiler): all I found in there was 1 human effigy and 1 soul vessel so as far as I can tell, there's nothing truly essential in there. there is also an estus flask shard down there

Answer (score 4):

After a little time has passed, a tombstone will appear where you killed Cale. If you interact with the tombstone, you can pay souls to speak with Cale's spirit, which will allow you to obtain the key.

This same technique works for all (or almost all?) NPCs in the game. If the NPC in question had items for sale, you're also able to browse their wares this way.